# Accessing a variable with .get() inside a function Python/Tkinter 3.4

Tags: python, function, tkinter

For my software major I'm creating a budgeting program and I'm currently stuck on a section with a function.
I have an entry box and button defined as:

```
incomeEntry = Entry(width=15)
testButton = Button(text="Save", command=Save)
```

And my Save function is:

```
def Save():
   a = incomeEntry.get()
   return(a)

a = Save()
print(a)
```

So what I'm trying to do is get the input from incomeEntry, and then return it outside the function so I can use it for later calculations.
If I change a = 3 it returns 3, but it doesn't work with the .get() function.

Could anyone help?

Comment: A variable like `a` is a reference to a _value_, not to another variable. Assigning, like `a = 3`, just makes `a` into a reference to a different value; it doesn't affect any other variable that had the old value. In particular, it doesn't affect the value stored in the `Entry`. So, if you call `incomeEntry.get()` again, you'll still get whatever value is displayed in the `Entry` widget, not 3. If you want to change that, you have to `set` a new value on the widget.

Comment: It still won't allow me to access what is in the entry widget and print it outside the function though? When I try the code that I have above it just doesn't display anything when I enter a value. @abarnert

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean? Do you get an error? What error?

Comment: @BryanOakley I get no error at all, it just doesn't print anything.

Comment: Probably a problem with incomeEntry not declared as global (or class variable). Please post a http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: There's not enough information to say for sure. You should create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). However, it seems like you misunderstand event driven programs. When you call `Save` from a button, the `return` statement is useless because the caller (the button, or more precisely the event loop) doesn't do anything with returned values.

Comment: @BryanOakley So is there any way of getting the value of the entry box back to the main program from the function 'Save()'?

Comment: Your function is donig the right thing, so it's unclear what your problem is.In a GUI program, functions like `Save` need to fetch values from widgets, which you appear to be doing.

Comment: @BryanOakley I want to send the value of the entry box outside of the function after I hit save so I can change/add or whatever to it.

Comment: @KyleR-: The value is available anywhere in your program, just by calling `incomeEntry.get()`. If you want to make it available in an `IntVar` instead of a widget, you can do that. If you want to stash it in a global, or an attribute of some object, or anything else, you can do that. But you don't actually need to do any of that, at least not for what you've shown us.

Comment: If you show us an MCVE, as you've been asked repeatedly, demonstrating where you want to access the value and can't figure out how to do that, then we can show you how to fix it. But otherwise, you're asking us to guess what part of your unseen program you don't understand, and there's no way we can do that.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution, IMO, is to use object oriented techniques to develop your program. You can then use object attributes to save values.

For example, the following shows how to call a function named `Save` via a button, and then another button will print what was saved via a `Print` button.

```
class Example(object):
    def __init__(self, ...):
        ...
        self.savedValue = None
        self.saveButton = tk.Button(..., command=self.Save)
        self.printButton = tk.Button(..., command=self.Print)
        ...

    def Save(self):
        ...
        self.savedValue = "whatever"
        ...

    def Print(self):
        ...
        print("last saved value: " + self.savedValue)
        ...
```

Comment: Ok so if I do this for example, how would I go about multiplying savedValue if it was an integer from like outside? For example, I have radio buttons and the code for it is:



`Frequencies = [
        ("Weekly", "1"),
        ("Fortnightly", "2"),
        ("Monthly", "3"),
    ]
v = StringVar()
v.set("1") #Initalize radio buttons
for text, frequency in Frequencies:
    b = ttk.Radiobutton(frame, text=text, variable=v, value=frequency)
    b.pack(anchor=SW)`

How do I make it so that I can set one of the radio buttons to like 4, then multiply savedValue by whatever radio button I press?

Comment: @KyleR-: Make sure your radiobutton variable is also an attribute of the class, then you just get the value and do the math `self.savedValue * self.radioButtonVar.get()` (with appropriate conversions to int if necessary)